# Using Zend2 Flashmessenger Controller/Plugin to show success msg

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am using FlashMessenger Controller/Plugin to show error messages, and that works fine. I am trying to show success messages by setting the namespace to success.

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Success msg!');
$successMessages = $this->flashMessenger()->hasSuccessMessages();
print_r($successMessages);exit;
$view = new ViewModel(array('success' => $successMessages));
```

When i print $successMessages it shows `Array()` as there are no messages to show.

Same is if i try to set namespace like this.

```
$this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('success')->addSuccessMessage('Success msg!');
$successMessages = $this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('success')->getMessages();
```

Is this the propper way to set namespace and how to show the message on view?
I am using this to show error messages, but it doesn't work with success messages.

```
    <?php if (!empty($this->messages)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->messages as $msg) : ?>
            <div class="error-box"><?php echo $this->translate($msg) ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This is [my FlashMessenger](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/Plugin/FlashMessenger.php) class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are writing and reading the messages in the same request. 
Think that    flashMessenger is mainly meant to save messages for later, as you can read in the [old  but meaningful ZF1 docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger):

> The FlashMessenger helper allows you to pass messages that the user
>   may need to see on the next request.

For example, you are in a request that comes from a form that is meant to add records to a list, in the controller/action that receives the form you save a record, write the message to the `flashmessenger`, and redirect the user to the controller/action that show the list of records again.
Something that you can see in this example from the [ZF2 mvc plugins docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-flashmessenger):

```
public function processAction()
{
    // ... do some work ...
    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('You are now logged in.');
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user-success');
}

public function successAction()
{
    $return = array('success' => true);
    $flashMessenger = $this->flashMessenger();
    if ($flashMessenger->hasMessages()) {
        $return['messages'] = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
    }
    return $return;
}
```

**If what you need is to read the messages in the same request (something that is also really common) you have to use the "Current Messages" methods of the helper.** So, instead of calling

```
$this->flashMessenger()->hasSuccessMessages()
```

you should call

```
$this->flashMessenger()->hasCurrentSuccessMessages()
```

and instead of calling

```
$this->flashMessenger()->getSuccessMessages()
```

you should call

```
$this->flashMessenger()->getCurrentSuccessMessages()
```

You can take a look at the full list of functions, if you go to the [Zend.Mvc.Controller.Plugin.FlashMessenger API docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Mvc.Controller.Plugin.FlashMessenger.html) and you search for "Current"

**UPDATE**

To show the messages in the view, you can use 2 approaches:

1. Retrieve the messages in the controller and send it to the view

   In the controller

   ```
   public function yourAction() {
       return array (
         '$successMessages' 
                   => $this->flashMessenger()->getCurrentSuccessMessages()       
       );
   }
   ```

   In the view

   ```
   //note that getCurrentSuccessMessages() returns an array, 
   //so in the vew $successMessages is an array
   foreach ($successMessages as $m) {
      echo $m;
   }
   ```
2. Retrieving directly in the view. The first thing that comes to mind is to use  the FlashMessenger view helper (`Zend\View\Helper \FlashMessenger`), but im afraid it doesnt have a function to get the current messages. So, you can extend it, or even more, you can write your own view helper. You have [here](http://rickdev.eu/home/zf2-flashmessenger-view-helper/) a good tutorial on how to do exactly this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used hasCurrentSuccessMessages() and now it is showing thw message when i print $successMessages. I have tried setting it as a variable to show on view, but i can not sucseed in showing the message on view. How can i show message on view page? Thank you again very much

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the following in a Controller:

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('test');

if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasSuccessMessages()) {
    print_r($this->flashMessenger()->getSuccessMessages());
}
```

This resulted in `Array ( [0] => test )`

Based on your question it appears you have not yet called on `getSuccessMessages()`

To get the messages into your ViewModel you could do something like this:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->setVariable('messages', ($this->flashMessenger()->hasSuccessMessages()) ? $this->flashMessenger()->getSuccessMessages() : null);
```

And in your View you could do this:

```
if (!is_null($this->messages)) {
    foreach ($this->messages as $message) {
        echo $message . "\n";
    }
}
```

Try reloading the page a few times to ensure that the message is visible. I personally use the EventManager (in my Controller) to check and handle messages stored in the flashMessenger(). For example:

```
public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
{
    parent::setEventManager($events);

    $events->attach('dispatch', function () {
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->setLocale('en');

        if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()) {
            $this->Flash()->Display($this->flashMessenger()->getMessages()); // Custom Controller Plugin
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I tried your example, but it shows an empty array. Array(). It doesn't pass if condition, but i print it outside of if and just shows empty array. What am i doing wrong, what could cause this problem? Thanks

Comment: The only thing I noticed based on my example was that I needed to reload the page after the initial load. Then the message appeared as I had expected it to. However I believe this was designed to be that way too. I don't think it matters but just in case, I'm using the latest ZF2 and the full build, not individual packages.